# Change one .json key value with an already existing one using jq

Tags: linux, json, jq

My test.json file contains the 2 keys:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "John"
}
```

And I want to achieve something like this:

```
{
    "id": "John"
}
```

where as you can see I change the value of the key `id` with the value of the key `name`. I'm guessing I have to use jq (I'm using Ubuntu) but I'm quite noob and I don't really now how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
jq '{id: .name}' input.json
```